# Notepad++ How do I remove everything not inside " "

Tags: notepad++

I have a data file which contains thousands of lines like this

```
<li data-value="2-30 Media - Rock that Brain">
  <span>2-30 Media - Rock that Brain</span>
</li>
<li data-value="2-30 Media - RockThatBrain">
  <span>2-30 Media - RockThatBrain</span>
</li>
<li data-value="2-30 Media - Test Box Quizz">
  <span>2-30 Media - Test Box Quizz</span>
</li>
```

I need the data to look like this.

```
2-30 Media - Rock that Brain
2-30 Media - RockThatBrain
2-30 Media - Test Box Quizz
```

any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regular expressions are what you want to use! Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to open the Replace dialog in Notepad++.

Assuming the text you want on each line is the contents of the `<span>` tag, do the following:

Find: `.*?<span>(.*?)<\/span><\/li>`

Replace: `$1\n`

Then just Replace All and that should do the trick.

So the regex will capture what's inside the `<span>` tag, then replace the whole `<li>` with the capture group and a newline.

Hope this helps! If you've anything else like this to do, [Regex101](https://regex101.com/) is a great tool for designing regexes.

Comment: @impulse - You're welcome! If this was the correct answer, then you can click on the tick beside it to mark it as such. Welcome to StackOverflow by the way!

Answer (score 0):

Use the 'Regular Expression' search and replace option.

Search for this: `.*?\"(?<name>.*?)\"`

and replace with this: `\1\r\n`